# Filtering dataframe records given a date range

Tags: python, datetime, list-comprehension

My df fields are **'User ID'** (string), **'Last Login'** (%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S). I want to know the **User IDs** that haven't Logged in for the past 3 months. The **'Last Login'** field contains 12 months of login history but only the last login per user. I need the **User ID** field to be preserved to compare against a list of **User IDs** that are in scope for my analysis.

I have tried a few variations of code using datetime but am struggling to get results.

Comment: Post a sample of your data, code, expected output, details about the specific issue you are having. See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Get the delta between today's date and last login, then apply a mask on the dataframe to get your final result.

```
import datetime as dt

current_date = dt.datetime.today()
df['Last Login Days'] = abs((df['Last Login'] - current_date).days)
absent_users_df = df[df['Last Login Days'] > 90]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

now = pd.to_datetime(time.ctime())
idx = (now - df['Last Login']) / np.timedelta64(1, 'M') <= 3
df2 = df[idx]
```